# Marking filesystems as unremovable in CentOS

Tags: centos, storage, removable-storage

**Disclaimer:** Not sure to post to serverfault or here. Please transfer as necessary.

I'm managing a CentOS 7.x terminal server. Recently, the filesystems on the server started to appear on users desktops as removable devices.

Instead of telling every user to update their desktop settings, I'm looking a way to mark the filesystems are non-removable.

The system is CentOS 7.4 1708 with XFCE and latest updates, and running a Dell PERC RAID controller.

**Update #1:** I've found the [relevant bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7555) in XFCE bugzilla and updated it. Will see how it goes.

**Update #2:** Installing `gvfs` and `udisks2` solved the problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug, rather than something that you're supposed to be able to fix yourself.

Comment: My logic was since the drives are managed by a RAID controller, the volumes are  flagged as removable. I'll check CentOS bug tracker nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: You can check to see if linux thinks the device is removable with `cat /sys/block/<DEVICE>/removable` (1 for removable) - problem might be with the kernel or the gui this might help to narrow it down.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin all values are strangely zero. Now it's narrowed to the GUI. Thanks for the direction, that helped a lot!

Comment: Specifying which desktop environment/file manager shows the problem might help then.

Comment: System is running XFCE. Already found the relevant bug report, and updated it. Will see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not on the kernel level, but on the XFCE (thunar to be exact) level. Without `gvfs` and `udisks`, XFCE cannot get advanced information about disks, and opts to show everything to be on the safe side. Installation of said packages have solved the problem.